# Customizing a datagridview runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C#,ASP.NET.
I am creating a small application where I want to list some data.

Below mentioned function binds data with 3 columns.

Property Name, Property 'ReferenceID' and Post Date.

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PROC_RECENT_HISTORY_HEADER"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Member);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    con.Close();

                }
```

Asp.net

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  class="form-control" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
                 <Columns> 

                     <asp:BoundField DataField="PRP_NAME" HeaderText="Property Name"/>      
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="PRP_REF_NO" HeaderText="Reference"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="PRP_CRDT" HeaderText="Post Date"/>  

                 </Columns>     
             </asp:GridView>
```

I want to display two extra columns along with this data.
One is for 'No.' as a serial number for each rows and another one column is 'Action', its like a hyperlink, when I click here page must be redirected to an action based on 'property_ReferenceID'  of corresponding row.

how to add columns run time ?

Comment: Please show us the exceptions.

Comment: You don't have a field called `PRP_ID` in your stored procedure. (so could be missing `PRP_ACT` too)

Comment: Add 2 columns to your stored procedure at runtime?  Your code above is not adding them at runtime. You need to update your stored procedure to select the two extra columns.

Comment: What do YOU mean by runtime?  You are listing the columns in your GridView at design time and binding them to data fields.  Those data fields need to exist in your data source before it can be bound.  Your error is telling you that they are not there.

Comment: Corrected my mistakes now, now it is error free, but how can I display extra columns ? one for serial number and one for a hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Here GridView1.DataSource = reader; if it consists of 3 columns then it will bind with 3 columns data.

step1: create the columns manually by adding columns
step2: store the data into datatable

```
   DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
   datatable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

step3 : the loop through each object from the datatable

```
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("PropertyName");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("PropertyID"); 
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Postdate");
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("columnName4");
        DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("columnName5");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc5);

        foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = row[propertyname];
            dr[1] = row[Propertytype];
            dr[2] = row[postdate];
            dr[3] = "YES";
            dr[4] = "NO";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```